# Cannot create form field for 'created_by' yet, because its related model 'users.User' has not been loaded yet

Tags: django

I recently installed Blogango, where I had the following error:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
 blogango.blogentry: 'created_by' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
```

So I added settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL and now I get the following message:

```
ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'created_by' yet, because its related model 'users.User' has not been loaded yet
```

I went through my settings.py where it calls `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'`, and moved it higher up on the settings.py to try and get it load sooner.

As requested:
    `created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, unique=False)`

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can we see the model for `created_by`?

Comment: Question now showing `created_by`.

Comment: What happens if you put `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` in quotes? i.e., `created_by = models.ForeignKey('settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL', unique=False)

Comment: When I change it with quotes I get:`ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'created_by' yet, because its related model 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL' has not been loaded yet`

Comment: Are you sure the question is correct? It claims you're referring `auth.User` while your quote from the settings clearly says `users.User`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Blogango (is it https://github.com/agiliq/django-blogango?) does not support the [custom user models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) introduced in Django 1.5.

The patch in Blogango should be pretty simple, just replace:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

with:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

in `django-blogango/blogango/models.py`.