# ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'author' yet, because its related model 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL' has not been loaded yet

Tags: python, django, custom-authentication

I am trying to set up a basic blog with a custom auth model. I am trying to get a simple form to work but somehow I am not able to make it work. I am not sure what is causing the error. This is a fresh app and a fresh project I am working on.

I tried to reference from the docs but I am not sure what I am doing incorrect. How can i fix this error? Thanks in advance

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project

Similar questions: [Cannot create form field for 'created_by' yet, because its related model 'users.User' has not been loaded yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083099/cannot-create-form-field-for-created-by-yet-because-its-related-model-users)

**My Current Code**

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  pass

class Post(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey('settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL')
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   text = models.TextField()
   created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py:

```
from blog.models import User

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
image = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),required=False)


class Meta():
    model = Post
    fields = ('author','title', 'text','image')
    widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
         }
```

views.py

```
from blog.forms import PostForm, CommentForm

class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
  ...
  form_class = PostForm
  model = Post
  def form_valid(self,form):
    if self.request.POST:
        post = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'blog.User'
```

admin.py:

```
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`, not the string `'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Comment: yes - i checked it out and that works. Thank you for helping here !!